# Перезаписать строку в файле С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Консольное приложение
Есть файл db.txt в котором хранится логин пароль и роль пользователя в формате LoginPasswordRole, к примеру
John12345Admin
Max67890User
LucaQWERTYAdmin,
Администратор может редактировать данные пользователей на заданую им строку.

То-есть в поле "Редактировать" администратор вводит LoginPasswordRole того, кого хочет заменить, затем вписывает новые данные которые должны сохранится в файл db.txt

Пробовал сделать сам, но не хватает опыта, может хоть намекните в какую сторону копать.
Смотрел в сторону replace,find.
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Там этот логин пароль один? Тогда открывайте файл на запись и пишите новые данные. Старые будут удалены.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.